# Differentiate between same event type within a method of an object

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, dom-events

How can I differentiate between the two event types in this object if they are the same type? As you can see below, it’s easy enough using the switch statement `switch(e.type)` because the event types are different, but what if they were both click events?

```
var obj = {
    init: function() {
        document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("click", this, false);
        document.getElementById("bar").addEventListener("touchstart", this, false);
    },
    handleEvent: function(e) {
        switch(e.type) {
            case "click":
                this.button();
                break;
            case "touchstart":
                this.button();
                break;
        }
    },
    sayHi: "holla",
    button: function() {
        alert(this.sayHi);
    }
};

obj.init();
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to determine which element triggered the event? You can use `e.target` for this.

Comment: `e.type` is the event type, `e.target` is the object that triggered the event.  If that's not enough differentiation, then don't point multiple listeners at the same handler.

Comment: I don't get it. If both were `click` events, both are of the same type, so you cannot distinguish between event types?